# Automatically set x=0, after each input/output ? ($AfterEachInputOutput)

Tags: evaluation, output, procedural-programming, variable, input

Is it possible to do something that I want, after each input/output **automatically and silently**?
I am looking for a feature like **$AfterEachInputOutput** in the following code :

Example : to set variable x to 0 after each output

```
In[1] $AfterEachInputOutput=(x=0;)
---> x=0 automatically and silently (not important because this is a starting step)
In[2] x=2;x+2
Out[2] 4
---> x=0 automatically and silently
In[3] If[x=0,100,-100]
Out[3] 100
---> x=0 automatically and silently
In[4] x=1;y=1;
---> x=0 automatically and silently
In[5] x+10
Out[5] 10
---> x=0 automatically and silently
```

I have tried

```
$Post=(x=0;)
```

or

```
$Preprint=(x=0;)
```

But it didn't work well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`CellEpilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellEpilog.html):

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellEpilog :> (x = 0)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Does it work similarly even if I change x=0 to arbitrary code ?

Comment: @imidak, it should afaik.